# Characteristics for wireless access point used in small/medium rooms with high demand

Tags: wifi, router, access-point

I'm looking for which characteristics I need to get a single access point that should serve 1 medium sized room (about 144 sq. meters) and 8 smaller adjacent rooms (about 28 sq meters), separated by 15cm wide walls made of concrete. I was looking [at this](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7089/7883) and the only thing I gathered was that I needed dual band. The clients would regularly be between 5 and 10, with the possibility of ballooning to 100-120 clients for some hours at any moment of the day. I have a router right now, but its throughput without too much stress (~25 clients) is pitiful given the total speed of the uplink and I need the clients to have reasonable internet speeds.

As characteristics I was thinking of MU-MIMO, 802.11ac standard, but after that, I don't know.

I don't need premium features, like NAS, as its main purpose would be as access point and would be hidden away in the roof of the bigger room.

Comment: No single consumer router that I know of will handle 120 simultaneous clients without crapping itself. You're looking for an enterprise-grade solution for that.

Comment: Take a look at Ubiquiti and Xclaim/Ruckus's stuff.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I didn't specify that I was looking for consumer grade. But, reading [the spec sheets](https://xclaim.s3.amazonaws.com/pdfs/datasheets/ds-xi-3.pdf) other than the promise to get +80 clients, I don't see any feature that separates them from the rest, which is what I'm kind of looking for with my question.